# How can we wrap an entire react native application inside another react native application?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

We have 2 independent react native applications, a parent and a child application. The requirement is to wrap the child app to be used inside the parent app. The child app should be accessible from the parent app in such a way that the child app opens and operates **inside** the parent app **without** triggering a launch as a separate independent app as in the case of deep linking.

We have already tried creating child application's .tgz file and import it into parent but while child has any dependencies then it start creating issues.

Also if such a scenario is possible, how can we control the navigation
in both the applications and how can we pass data between the 2 app?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would take from the child app the screens and components and integrate them into the parent app navigation, like a separate stack per example, and install the child dependencies into the parent app (without react-native, react ..)

another option is to use a conditional return in App.js of parent app, to render appropriate navigation container depending on a condition that you can control inside both apps using redux.

return of App.js parent:

```js
if (loadParent){
return (
  <ParentNavigator/>
)
}else{
  return (
  <ChildNavigator/>
)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if the child app is a complex application with so many screens and dependencies.Will Integrating all would be feasible?

Comment: yes, I think its possible, you can even put a condition in you App.js return, that will define which app to load using redux, see updated answer